# В чем заключаются должностные обязанности программиста?

Tags: работа

Здравствуйте, народ!

Может кто подскажет или объяснит (с примерами), в чем заключается работа, включающая в себя следующие обязанности? Только ответьте серьезно, может кто-то этим занимается и объяснит популярно.

Так вот:

> техническая работа программиста (настройка систем управления, установка модулей, доработка функций, исправление ошибок, техническое администрирование сайтов).

Может кто что прокомментирует? По данным пунктам, что они в себе заключают... Вообще это сложно или нет? И что нужно знать, чтобы выполнять эти задачи?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 10):

Пишут по умному, а смысл везде одинаковый. Точного определения Вы не найдете, кроме как в самой компании. 
Вот что я вижу:
настройка систем управления - так как речь идет о сайтах, то Вам скорее всего придется настраивать админку их собственной CMS системы. 
про модули тоже громкие слова, но на деле, к примеру, может быть очень просто:подключить модуль новостей... 
доработка функций - скорее всего надо будет писать к их системе некоторые дополнительные возможности (к примеру у них нет голосования и галочкой их не добавить)
техническое администрирование сайтов-наверное вам дадут пароли от хостингов и там вы уже будете мелкие настройки производить.

Все это не сложно думаю, но муторно. А слова технический добавляют, так как это стандарт при поиске на такую работу.
P.S.: Будете устанавливать их сайты с их цмс системой, регистрировать домены и т.д. Может писать какой то дополнительный код для расширения. Не думаю что это сложно.

Comment: И какая зарплата приемлема для таких обязанностей (на глаз)?

Comment: Смотря какой город. Можно на 30-50 согласится в Москве. Хотя конкуренция. Зп вообще зависит от другого фактора-насколько дорого ты сможешь себя продать.

Comment: Но я не хочу чтоб мне платили за то что  не знаю, да и выдавать себя за того кем я являюсь тоже не хочу. Совестно. Может я не прав?

Comment: Нет не правы!) Вы достигнете такого уровня за мес или два, но если дадите слабину сейчас, то будете потом еще год добиваться повышения! Так что подумайте!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Ну судя по всему есть сайт, который необходимо сопровождать и дорабатывать. Говорить о сложности работы тяжело, так как не понятно что за сайт, на чём написан и т. д. Судя по тому что необходимо "устанавливать модули" думаю что вероятнее всего сайт сдеан на CMS. Вероятнее всего что то типа Joomla или Drupal. Если так, то в принципе ничего сложного нет, но временами могут возникать некоторые трудности... Вообще желательно хорошо знать html, css, иметь общее представление о php.

Comment: Я php более менее знаю. HTML - на уровне таблиц. А CSS - не доводилось познавать...

Comment: Сходите на собеседование и сами спросите о том, чем будете заниматься, пусть покажут.

Comment: Если Джумла и Друпал то труда понять их вам не составит.
CSS придет когда захотите цвета поковырять.

Answer (score 1):

По описанию требуется web-программист или web-мастер. Одним знанием HTML и CSS не обойдетесь. Если у них CMS, это как минимум PHP + MySQL (или иная связка). В целом, работа неплохая, интересная.

Comment: А вообще на таких работах, дают хоть время освоиться? Или нужно сразу сесть и усиленно печатать? Как бы спешка присутствует на таких "должностях"?

Comment: Это уже будет зависеть непосредственно от руководства. Одно скажу, люди всегда хотят получить всё и побыстрее ;)

Comment: Но а как тогда непосредственный опыт получить? Если все и побыстрее? Нужно же с чего то начинать....

Comment: На работе дают время освоится как устроенна система, неделю минимум,по пути дают задания мелкие.Вот оттуда и черпаем опыт)